Is my clothes dryer exhaust leaking due to a deformed outlet pipe?
My dryer's exhaust has been leaking. I noticed that the  pipe is pretty deformed in back. I'm wondering if that could be why it won't seal back there, if this is the type of thing that's easy to repair, and if enough tape could possibly fix the problem.


What do you have it connected to?

Gas or electric? While most of the issue is the same, this is critical with gas because the exhaust contains not just hot humid air but also combustion products - which can include carbon monoxide in certain circumstances.

I would also check that the pipe isn't blocked with lint somewhere.

The issue is not whether the pipe is deformed. It is whether the pipe that is connected to it is sized correctly.
Connecting pipes go over (slip over the outside of) the exhaust pipe. You then use a clamp to secure the connecting pipe to the exhaust pipe. A lot of people don't do this figuring that the dryer will never be moved around.

Yeah, the exit pipe needs to be round for a strap clamp to do its job or for it to fit to a rigid offset duct well. Gently reshape it with hands or pliers as well as you can, then be sure the hose or fitting you're connecting is the right size to fit snugly over the pipe. Lightly tighten the clamp to avoid damaging the outlet pipe again.
